# использование include для считывания файла в сткроку

Tags: c++, c

Директива `#include` по сути, просто считывает содержимое файла в ставляет в итоговый файл, меня же интересует можно ли с помощью макросов поместить результат этой директивы в строку? Сделать что-то вроде того:

```
 std::string alfa = MY_MAGIC_DEFINE(#include "include.hpp");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это потенциально возможно посредством [`std::embed`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1040r1.html):

```
constexpr ::std::span<::std::byte const> fxaa_binary{::std::embed("file.bin")};
```

Ну а пока используйте ресурсы (.rc) или вкомпиливайте вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно на чистом C/C++.

---

Самое близкое, что я нашел, это хак, якобы работающий на MSVC ([из-за их бага](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997129/in-c11-what-should-happen-first-raw-string-expansion-or-macros)), требующий специальных изменений включаемого файла:

> **[How to include a file in cpp as both a string and code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103029)**
>
> test.inc:
>
> ```
> #ifdef ASSTRING
> R"foo(
> #else
> int do () { return 23; }
> // )foo";
> #endif
> ```
>
> main.cpp
>
> ```
> #define ASSTRING
> const char s[] =
> #include "test.inc";
>
> #undef ASSTRING
> #include "test.inc"
>
> printf ( "hello\n%s\n%i\n", s+6, me() );
> ```

---

Еще вариант - [использовать какие-нибудь дополнительные кастомные препроцессоры, вроде m4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28103339/2752075).

Comment: Можно, добавить имя макроса к тексту в включаемое файле, потом определить этот макрос в коде, и подключить этот файл. При этом там может быть список, по одному макросу с текстом на каждую строку. Что нибудь типа `__x("my text")`